# Palindromes And Project Euler C++ Version -Tips

Tags: c++

Can Anyone Tell Me What's Wrong In My Code?

Thank you :)

```
// A palindromic number reads the same both ways.
// The largest palindrome made from the product of two 2-digit numbers is 9009 = 91 × 99.
// Find the largest palindrome made from the product of two 3-digit numbers.

#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int x = 2;
    int  product;
    int  n, digit, rev = 0;
    int  greatest = 0;

    for(int i = 2;i<100;i++){
        product = x * i;
        n = product;
        cout << x << " * " << i << " = " << product << endl;
        do
        {
            digit = product % 10;
            rev = (rev * 10) + digit;
            product = product / 10;
        } while(product != 0);
        cout << " The reverse of the number is: " << rev << endl;
        if(n == rev){
            cout << "Therefore Palindrome" << endl;
            if(rev > greatest){
                cout << "REV Greater Than Greatest Palindrome" << endl;
                greatest = rev;
            }
        }
        if(i == 99){
            if(x < 99){
                x++;
                i = 1;
                cout << "Go For The Next Loop" << endl;
            }
        }
    }
    cout << "The Greatest Palindrome Number Is " << greatest << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What output do you get? What output do you expect?

Comment: Post a [MCVE] please.

Comment: The way you are calculating the "reverse" of a product does not work. It just multiplies by 10 every loop and adds the last digit. you have integer overflow there

Comment: A good start would be to check the three-digit numbers instead of the one- and two-digit ones.

Comment: Debugger.  Use a debugger.  A debugger will allow you to execute one statement at a time (stepping) and *watch* the values of variables.  A lot faster than posting to StackOverflow and waiting for somebody to debug your program for you.

Comment: You can develop faster code by treating the input as a string of characters.  No need to convert to integer, using math to isolate digit, then check.  You can treat a `std::string` as an array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Several things:

- You should be counting *down* from 999 thru 100.
- You should be using two loops for the two factors of your product
- `rev` should be initially zero before each entrance into your inner do-while loop

The results would look something like this, with all but the detected palindromes and final result being output (the amount of worthless noise in your output is mind-bending)

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int  product;
    int  n, digit, rev = 0;
    int  greatest = 0;

    for(int i = 999;i>=100; --i)
    {
        for (int j =999; j>=100; --j)
        {
            product = j * i;
            n = product;
            rev = 0;
            do
            {
                rev = (rev * 10) + (product % 10);
                product /= 10;
            } while(product != 0);

            if(n == rev)
            {
                cout << "Palindrome : " << i << " * " << j << " = " << n << endl;
                if(rev > greatest)
                    greatest = rev;
            }
        }
    }
    cout << "The Greatest Palindrome Number Is : " << greatest << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

This will conclude the correct answer you seek.

**Faster**

Optionally, you can squeeze better performance out of this by understanding a few additional details:

- The task is to find the largest palindrome, not just the *longest* palindrome. Therefore, once you find one, any product, palindrome or not, that is a smaller magnitude than the current largest palindrome is pointless to even check and the inner loop can be terminated (thus the reason you're counting *down*).
- A little number crunching will allow you to conclude that at least one of the factors *must* be divisible by 11. I won't cover why, but do the math, it's true. Therefore, you can make one of your loops a count-down from the largest 3-digit multiple of 11 (990) to 100, in steps of (-11).

The result looks like this:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int  greatest = 0;

    for(int i = 999;i>=100; --i)
    {
        for (int j =990; j>=100; j-=11)
        {
            int product = j * i;
            if (product < greatest)
                break;

            int n = product;
            int rev = 0;
            do
            {
                rev = (rev * 10) + (product % 10);
                product /= 10;
            } while(product != 0);

            if(n == rev)
            {
                cout << "Palindrome : " << i << " * " << j << " = " << n << endl;
                if(rev > greatest)
                    greatest = rev;
            }
        }
    }
    cout << "The Greatest Palindrome Number Is : " << greatest << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

**Output**

```
Palindrome : 995 * 583 = 580085
Palindrome : 993 * 913 = 906609
The Greatest Palindrome Number Is : 906609
```

Comment: Ur answer was wonderful thanks alot
but One thing i dont understand is why i should use two loops it bugs me
can u tell me how the variables values will change and how will the program process the values of variables ... will that lead to my same products?
one more thing .... i was told not to use break unless necessary and it makes u a bad programmer 
thanks alot sir much appreciated

Comment: You don't *have* to use two loops. But in reality, that's effectively what you were doing in your code with the increment of `x` and resetting of `i`.  Regarding using `break`, there are some cases where it is an elegant alternative to encoding complexity in loop conditionals, and in-fact brings *clarity*, not obfuscation, to code. This is a reasonable example of that. Finally, the most relevant thing that makes "bad programmers" are "bad instruction", be it human, text, or just plain not enough. [You can avoid using `break`](https://ideone.com/qcFby6), but is it really "better" ? Not really.

Comment: U are a true leader and a philosopher sir.... May u enlighten me more? Why Did u use (--i) instead of (i--) 
thanks alot i really cant believe u have done all this sir